# Remove specific characters from row using a list

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I would like to remove parts of a string if the string begins with items in a list.

Ideally, I'd like to have the characters from the list get stripped from the entire string in each row, if the row value begins with the list item.

For example:

"1/2 Any Street" would update to "Any Street"

```
prefix_list = ["1/2 ", "1/3 ", "1/4 ", "1/5 ", "1/6 ", "1/7 ", "1/8 ", "1/9 ", "1/10 ", "3/4 ", "N ", "S ", "E ", "W "]
for fix in prefix_list:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(geocoded_fc_copy, 'STREET') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if fix in row[0]:
                cursor.updateRow(row[0][len(fix):])
```

I know this is not correct but I do not have the experience doing this.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

This code will return a new string with the items in your list removed from that string.

Still you do not want to start a new cursor for each list item as that will slow your code down a lot.  Better start the cursor, get the street name, pass the street name to the clean_address function, if there is a change to the address do the update.

```
def clean_address(in_address):
    prefix_list = ["1/2 ", "1/3 ", "1/4 ", "1/5 ", "1/6 ", "1/7 ", "1/8 ", "1/9 ", "1/10 ", "3/4 ", "N ", "S ", "E ", "W "]
    for item in prefix_list:
        if item in in_address:
            in_address = in_address.replace(item, '')
            return in_address
        else:
            pass
in_address = '1/6 Foo St.'

cleaned = clean_address(in_address)
print(cleaned)
```

Comment: This will return `None` if `in_address` doesn't contain any of those prefixes

Comment: Now it'll only ever check the first prefix

Comment: Right, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

This situation really calls for [re — Regular expression operations - Python 3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).  It is better to match a pattern than to enumerate all of the possibilities that may exist.  What if there is a "1/13" you didn't anticipate, or what if a street starts with "SE" instead of just "S" or "E"?  What if a street has both a fraction and direction?

```py
>>> import re
>>> streets = [
...   "1/2 Any Street",
...   "N Any Street",
...   "Any Street",
...   "1/13 Any Street",
...   "1/13 NE Any Street",
...   "NE 1/13 Any Street"
... ]
>>> print(*[re.sub(r"^(\d+/\d+ |[NSEW]+ )*", "", street) for street in streets], sep="\n")
Any Street
Any Street
Any Street
Any Street
Any Street
Any Street
>>>
```

Used in a cursor:

```py
import re
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(geocoded_fc_copy, 'STREET') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow([re.sub(r"^(\d+/\d+ |[NSEW]+ )*", "", row[0])])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over all prefixes and use .startswith and .replace:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy
fc = r"C:\TEMP\streets.shp"
fieldname = "STREET"
prefix_list = ["1/2 ", "1/3 ", "1/4 ", "1/5 ", "1/6 ", "1/7 ", "1/8 ", "1/9 ", "1/10 ", "3/4 ", "N ", "S ", "E ", "W "]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["STREET"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for p in prefix_list:
            if row[0].startswith(p): #If the field value starts with the prefix
                print(row[0])
                newval = row[0].replace(p, "") #Replace prefix with empty string
                row[0] = newval
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```